Understanding the orthochronous condition for Lorentz transforms
Let M be a Minkowki spacetime and g be an inner product on M with signature (+,+,+,-). Further, let ${e_a}$ and ${\hat{e_a}}$ be orthonormal bases for M, related by a linear transformation L such that $L(e_a) = \hat{e_a}$. Define the 4x4 matrix $\Lambda^{a}_b$ so that $\Lambda^{a}_u\hat{e_a} = e_u$. It can be shown that any matrix $\Lambda$ defined in such a way satisfies $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda = \eta$ ($\eta = diag(1,1,1,-1)$), or in other words that $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz transformation.
This is where my question begins. There are two ways of interpreting $\Lambda$: either as the matrix of the (active) linear transformation $L^{-1}$ relative to the basis $\hat{e_a}$, or as a passive coordinate transformation from the basis ${e_a}$ to the basis $\hat{e_a}$. Both interpretations of $\Lambda$ are of course physically equivalent, but there is a subtlety in the mathematical formalism between these two views that I am having a hard time finding a resolution for.
My problem is this: a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ is defined to be orthochronous if $\Lambda^{4}_4 \ge 1$. If $\tau$ is the set of all timelike vectors in M, we can define an equivalence relation on $\tau$ as follows: v~w if $g(v,w) < 0$. It turns out that this equivalence relation has only two equivalence classes, $\tau^{+}$ and $\tau^{-}$, which we assign arbitrarily and which are called future directed vectors and past directed vectors respectively. Now, to me it makes perfect sense that an (active) orthogonal transformation such as $L^{-1}$ as defined earlier could be called orthochronous. The condition is simply that for $v\in\tau$, $g(v,L(v)) < 0$, which just means that L sends future pointing vectors to future pointing vectors and past pointing vectors to past pointing vectors. Viewing $\Lambda$ as the transformation $L^{-1}$ relative to the basis $\hat{e_a}$, it is clear why $\Lambda$ is called orthochronous if $\Lambda^{4}_4 \ge 1$, since this condition is equivalent to the statement that for any timelike vector $v = v^a\hat{e_a}$, the fourth component of $v$ and $\Lambda(v^a)$ have the same sign, which is equivalent to the statement that $g(v,L^{-1}(v)) < 0$. However, when $\Lambda$ is viewed not as an active transformation from one vector to another but as a coordinate transformation, my understanding breaks down. How can a coordinate transformation be called orthochronous or nonorthochronous at all? The coordinate transformation is, as viewed from our Minkowski space M, just the identity map, and since the equivalence relation ~ on $\tau$ makes no reference to the coordinate expression of any vector in $\tau$, I don't see how changing our coordinate system could have any effect on the time orientation of a timelike vector.
Any help in resolving this difficulty would be appreciated.
Thanks.

"How can a coordinate transformation be called orthochronous or nonorthochronous at all? " Why do you feel the need to use the terminology at all then, if you don't believe it's applicable? You could save it for active transformations only. Anyway, a passive non-orthochronous transformation, as I understand, reverses sign of the time coordinate for time-like vectors, i.e. if  for a time like vector $L$ maps $t$ to $t'$ and $t+1$ to $t'_1$ then $t<t+1$ but $t'_1>t'$. Is that not good enough to be considered orthochronous?

@NicholasTodoroff I'd like to understand what it means because the interpretation of a Lorentz transform as a coordinate transformation is more physically relevant than as a linear map. I don't understand what you are saying in the second part of your answer.

You have coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$ and coordinates $(x',y',z',t')$ for the same physical point (linked by a passive Lorentz transformation). The coordinates for another point in the future are $(x,y,z,t+\Delta t)$ and $(x',y',z',t'')$ for positive $\Delta t$. If the transformation is orthochronous, then $t'<t''$ just like $t<t+\Delta t$. If the transformation is not orthochronous, then $t'>t''$. This seems like a reasonable use of the word "orthochronous" to me.

Most misunderstandings of Minkowski space comes from interpreting it as as a space time. But space-time yields  no physical base for dealing with a vector space: Spacelike vectors do not exist (except in rigid bodies as chains of atoms at a fixed time) and timelike vectors are clock traces, which are not observable.
The classical Minkoswki space is the local tangent space to timelike curves, the spatial frame bundle is free for a choice in $O(3)$. The result is a free Lagrangian $$L=\dot x_0^2 - {\dot{\vec x}}^2.$$ Active or passive: The direction of moving in time splits the frame bundle. In physics no one is interested in spacelike curves except for technical calculations as paths of integration.
Much more involved and obeservable is the Minkowski tangent space of frequencies and wave vectors of fields.
In flat space-time the invariant form is $$\partial_t^2 - {\vec \nabla_x}^2 + m^2 =0 $$ and the sign of the frequency in $$(\hbar^2) \left(\omega^2 - \vec k^2\right) = m^2 c^2$$ splits retarded and advanced potentials or particles and antiparticles.
Completely clear is the distinction for fermionic particles represented in different irreducible representations of the Clifford algebra $\mathit{Cl}(3,1)$.
